# Simple question in "Sheaves in geometry and logic"

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

There's an argument I don't understand in "Sheaves in geometry and logic" by Mac Lane and Moerdijk, that seems a priori easy but I can't see it.

Page 174, diagram (10) (involving the power contravariant functor/internal pullback along $g$ and $g'$), they claim that the bottom left square is "formally a pullback", and I'm not sure to understand why it works. Can anyone clarify this little point ?

Thanks.

PS: sorry that I can't rewrite the whole proof/diagrams for people without the book to get it. I'll try to add some details if you think such questions is not good for this site.

Comment: It is a general fact about commutative squares involving binary products of that form. You can deduce it from the pullback pasting lemma, if you like.

Comment: Ah, right, thanks for the hint, I think I understand now.